# How can I show only some options using django and select?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, python-3.x

Hello I have this code using Django in a HTML file :

```
<select class="form-control" data-formsource="test" id="id_test1" name="type">
{% for x,y in opt %}
    <option value="{{ y }}" data-select="{{ y }}">{% trans y %}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

And there is an option which is "available" but I don't want to see this option ... How can I do this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" data-formsource="test" id="id_test1" name="type">
{% for x,y in opt %}
    {% if x != 'available' %}
        <option value="{{ y }}" data-select="{{ y }}">{% trans y %}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I don't know why I try your solution but it does not work ... :/

Comment: Can you post your `opt` variable but I'll edit my answer so you can try that

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: Provide the view your using so we can see what’s in the opt variable. Edit your post here for that.

Comment: Actually I can't do a print to see the value of the variables ... :/

Comment: You should just copy your view and update your post with that information. That should be enough. No need to print anything